# Is there a Stack Exchange site for "Punctuation" ..or Grammar?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've intentionally misused "quotes" for emphasis in the title of this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Potentially, a question about punctuation or grammar could be asked at [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). From their [What topics can I ask about here? page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and their [Tour page](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), they allow questions about Grammar and Punctuation.

[English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is another site where questions about punctuation and grammar are on topic (according to that linked help page).

But make sure that your question is not a proofreading question, as that is off topic.

Comment: Thanks! I will post to English Language and Usage and carefully disguise my need for proof-reading as an intellectual pursuit.

Comment: Best not to disguise anything (they will most likley see through it), but ask a specific question about the punctuation and/or grammar problem itself

Comment: I think I came to the same conclusion that my disguise would fail. Here is my question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205864/problem-solved-or-problem-solved-or-problem-solved